# What engineering software tools should we support on EE?

Tags: support, off-topic

I see a lot of questions [such as this very recent one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/544993/what-is-the-proper-method-to-become-able-to-connect-conduit-signals-inside-qsys) that is requesting help/support with Qsys with the specific question being: -

> *it is possible to be able to connect conduits together between
> different modules within Qsys.*

But there are questions raised about PCB packages, CAD packages, Sim packages and most (if not nearly all) are really asking for support help.

Is this going beyond what is reasonably expected for EE?

Should we be doing this?

Are there some packages that we should not try to give support on?

Should we be supporting all EE software design packages?

Should we be supporting any EE software design packages?

I can't see a way of not supporting LTSpice given that nearly every man woman and child will use it at some time but, more generally, are there some software tool types that we should never consider supporting?

Comment: Fortunately, or unfortunately, people hear that EESE is the quickest way to get great quality assistance, including software packages and simulators. So our community will continue to attract the questions

Comment: @Marla I don't deny that but, should we be more inclined to have a policy?

Comment: There has been one question cited are there more? I think the rate for questions like this is around 1 per day, is it really a problem?

Comment: @VoltageSpike it sticks in my mind that it happens at least daily.

Comment: Could you cite more questions?

Comment: In the last 31 days there have been 14 altium questions for example. Same period 43 questions tagged LTSpice. 8 Eagle questions. Kicad = 10. Multisim = 14 etc..

Comment: And those are packages that we shouldn't support?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem supporting all of them. It's one of those cases where if you're not interested, just don't answer. I have  had [altium](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/altium) and [proteus](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proteus) on my ignore list for a long time.

It may suck to pay thousands for badly supported software and it would perhaps be fair to force the company to uphold their end of the bargain, but isn't this (or at least the original stackoverflow) a place for professionals to help other professionals? Those professionals will undoubtedly use commercial or otherwise rare software, some of which may not even *have* support anymore due to aging products etc.